# Error When Generating Image Crops In tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

so I am Loading My datasetvia keras.utils and after that i want to generate 10 random 256x256 crops from each image. when i try to do that i get this error. can anyone help me out to fix it?

```py
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(DATADIR, image_size=(2044, 1533), batch_size = 32)

# Define a function to generate 10 random crops for each image
def generate_crops(image):
    crops = [tf.image.random_crop(image, size=[256, 256, 3]) for _ in range(10)]
    return crops

# Apply the function to each image in the dataset
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: (generate_crops(x), y))
```

this is error:

```
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_12/3481008463.py", line 9, in None  *
        lambda x, y: (generate_crops(x), y)
    File "/tmp/ipykernel_12/3481008463.py", line 5, in generate_crops  *
        crops = [tf.image.random_crop(image, size=[256, 256, 3]) for _ in range(10)]

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 4 and 3 for '{{node random_crop/GreaterEqual}} = GreaterEqual[T=DT_INT32](random_crop/Shape, random_crop/size)' with input shapes: [4], [3].
```

Comment: The error is due to a mismatch between the image dimensions and the size argument in tf.image.random_crop, which expects [height, width, channels]. To resolve this, specify the size as [256, 256, 3] for generating 256x256 crops from each image.Thanks.